# jQuery .append() multiple #id's with one line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm using the jQuery .append() function to input content into HTML elements via their id like so;

```
  function returnGameDetailed(data) {
      $('#game-synopsis').append(data.results.deck);
  }
```

For some of the data.results I need to append them to multiple elements, is there a correct method to do this?

In the documentation I can only see a method for multiple inputs to the same element, not reversed.

Here's what i've attempted;

```
  $('#game-title').$('#purchase-amazon').append(data.results.name);
```

and

```
  $('#game-title', '#purchase-amazon').append(data.results.name);
```

Comment: `$('#game-title, #purchase-amazon').append(data.results.name);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost right. The correct way is here:

```
$('#game-title, #purchase-amazon').append(data.results.name);
```

However, I'd recommend you to use classes instead:

```
$('.elements-to-insert').append(data.results.name);

<div class="elements-to-insert" id="game-title"></div>
<div class="elements-to-insert" id="purchase-amazon"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I agree using classes is a better approach, I'm going to change it to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Give both elements a class and then append to that class

```
  $('.className').append(data.results.name);
```

The elements having the className will get appended with the html